# Catching an OutOfMemory Exception C#

Tags: c#, memory, out-of-memory

Hoping someone can help me out, I am out of ideas!

I have a intensive method that creates an object and puts it in a queue. It looks a lot like:

```
private void LongMethod()
  {
     for (int i=0; i<number;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<number; j++)
        {
         object o = new object();
         queue.enqueue(o);
        }
    }
  }
```

However, sometimes `number` has a very large value and so depending on the amount of memory available, this sometimes throws an OutOfMemory Exception.

So what I have been trying to do is this:

```
private bool CheckingMethod(number)
{
long initialValue =   System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64;

object o = new object();
queue.Enqueue(o)

long difference = initialValue - System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64;

if(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo.TotalPhysicalMemory <= difference * number * number)
    {
     return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And then the calling method can do:

```
private void CallingMethod(number)
    {
     if(CheckingMethod(number)
      {
       LongMethod(number);
      }
    }
```

I'm attempting to check before running the longMethod, whether it will cause an OOM exception. My issue is that `difference` will give me a drastically different value and so I sometimes still encounter the outOfMemory exception. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: how big is 'number'? How large are the objects you are allocating?

Comment: Choosing the right data type is the right way...

Comment: @MitchWheat number is a user input, and the idea is to allow the highest 'number' possible, without throwing an exception. That's what I'm trying to figure out. I want to know how much memory each object is using.

Comment: @x...Can you elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: "check before running the longMethod, whether it will cause an OOM exception" :) You may also want to get result that the method would return before even running the method - that will give you insane speed up too.

Comment: Not must raw size by the queue needs contiguous memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may well be that you need to *re-design* this algorithm so that it does not attempt to put "everything" into a queue ... or, perhaps, does not use a queue at all. For instance, could an *iterator* be used here?

The logic of `LongMethod`, which is presently expressed as a double-nested loop, *could* be equivalently expressed as an algorithm which (given a `struct` of some kind to "hold state" between calls), *returns* (or "yields") a new `object()` each time.

A re-expression of this algorithm would relieve you from the obligation to generate a tremendous number of objects "all at once," and to place them in a queue "all at once." Instead, it might be possible to produce the objects one-at-a-time "on demand," and/or to produce and enqueue "some" objects while retaining the ability to produce "more of them" at some future time.

You really can't "catch" an OOM exception:   when such a thing occurs, "the program is already nine-tenths dead in the water, and almost certain to quickly finish drowning." You need some kind of an algorithm redesign that eliminates the need for "such a massive 'queue.'"